# Perform "which" bypassing aliases and functions

Tags: bash, alias

```sh
$ command gs
GPL Ghostscript 8.70 (2009-07-31)
Copyright (C) 2009 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
GPL Ghostscript 8.70: Cannot open X display `(null)'.
**** Unable to open the initial device, quitting.

$ which gs
alias gs='git status'
        /opt/rh/rh-git29/root/usr/bin/git
```

How do I do `which` for ghostscript so as to find the path for it, kind of like `which $(command gs)`?

One way is definitely by unaliasing `gs` first.

```sh
$ unalias gs
$ which gs
/usr/bin/gs
```

Any better way?

Output of `type which`:

```
$ type which
which is aliased to `alias | /usr/bin/which --tty-only --read-alias --show-dot --show-tilde'
```

Comment: `which` doesn't find alias,  it locates a program file in the your path.

Comment: Something is strange. Show output of `type which`.

Comment: It should look better after `unalias which gs`.

Comment: You can bypass aliases by prefixing them with a back slash.

Comment: `which` is not properly standardized; without details about which version you are using, this is guesswork / moving target. Probably try to use the POSIX standard commands `type` and `command` instead?

Comment: I believe [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/525242) answer might be very useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was working on a company machine. The comment from @Cyrus showed that `which` is aliased to `alias`. Doing this worked as it should have:

```
$ /usr/bin/which gs
/usr/bin/gs
```